# Why do functions called in a ruby rescue block fail to modify the variables?

Tags: ruby, loops, exception

I have a situation which is comparable with this code:

```
i=0
def add_one(i)
  i+=1
  puts "FUNCTION:#{i}"
end

begin
  puts "BEGIN:#{i}"
  raise unless i>5
rescue
  add_one(i)
  puts "RESCUE:#{i}"
  retry
end
```

When I run this, I am seeing this output repeatedly:

```
BEGIN:0
FUNCTION:1
RESCUE:0
```

This version increments `i` and completes the program perfectly:

```
i=0
begin
  puts "BEGIN:#{i}"
  raise unless i>5
rescue
  i+=1
  puts "RESCUE:#{i}"
  retry
end
```

Why is there a difference? How can I get a function in the rescue block to actually modify a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because in your `add_one` function you are not manipulating the same `i` variable as outside of the function.

Let me try to explain that a bit. In Ruby, you deal with generally mutable objects (notable exceptions are numbers, `true`, `false`, and `nil`). A variable is a pointer to such an object. Multiple variables can point to the same object.

```
a = 123
b = a
```

Now `a` and `b` refer to the very same object. If you assign a new object to one of `a` or `b`, they they will refer to different object again, while still retaining the name.

What you have above are local variables. These are only valid inside a *scope*, mostly the duration of a method. If you create a new local variable (by assigning a value to it), it will only be valid during the duration of the method and will be garbage collected sometime after leaving the method.

Now as I said above, most objects in Ruby are mutable, meaning that you can change them while retaining the variable pointers. An example is adding an element to an array:

```
array = []
array << :foo
```

Now the `array` variable will still refer to the same Array object it got initialized with. But you have change the object. If you would assign the `array` variable a new array like

```
array = [:foo]
```

it would look like the same object, but effectively, they are different (you can verify that be checking the `object_id` method on every object. If it is the same, you are referring to the very same object)

Now when you do `i += 1` in your `add_one` method, you are effectively running `i = i + 1` which will set the i variable to a new value in the local method scope. You are not actually changing the `i` variable but you assign it a new value in the local method scope. This means that the variable named `i`  on your outer scope (i.e. the begin/end block) will refer to a different object than the `i` variable in your `add_one` method. This is because while they have the same name, they have a different scope. The inner scope always masks the outer scope, so while you have variables with the same names in different scopes, they do not interfer in any way (this changes when dealing with instance or class variables)

Unfortunately, as I said above, numbers are immutable. You can't change them. If you assign a new number to a variable, it is a new object. Thus, you can't change the value of a variable pointing to a number in another scope as the code that changes the value.

To circumvent this, you could either return a value from your function and explicitly assign it to your `i` variable in the outer scope like this

```
i = 0

def add_one(i)
  i+=1
  puts "FUNCTION:#{i}"
  return i
end

i = add_one(i)
```

or you could use instance variable of an object like this

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @i = 0
  end

  def add_one
    @i += 1
  end

  def do_something
    begin
      puts "BEGIN:#{@i}"
      raise unless @i>5
    rescue
      add_one
      puts "RESCUE:#{@i}"
      retry
    end
  end
end

# create a new object and run the instance method
Foo.new.do_something
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation - I understand this a lot better now!

Answer (score 2):

The "i" in add_one is a local reference, to the parameter--nutshell is that it's a different "i".

You'd need to use a variable in the correct scope.